# When I rendered my model with Cycles, it seemed to flatten out

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering

[image][image]I noticed that when I rendered my model with Cycles, it seemed to flatten out. No matter how much more I rounded the model out, and no matter how I lit it to eliminate shadows, there was still a hint of this. I noticed what looked like other examples of this online. Is there an adjustment I should know about? Also, I tried to re-enter color and texture information and render with the Render engine but this does not work now. Did I change something by using Cycles that I cannot reset?

Comment: Shadows add depth (Roundness).

Comment: you have any modifiers on that moose?

Answer (score 2):

Is this the issue you have mentioned?

A flat shaded model without shadows as shown in the image below.

[image]

Check your "Ambient Occlusion" option under the tab "World". If you have set its "Factor" value to a higher value like "1" you will face this issue.

[image]

Try unchecking the Ambient Occlusion option or turn the factor value down to a smaller value like 0.05 or so as required. This might help resolve the issue.

[image]

Furthermore, darken the background color towards black, otherwise the model receive equal amount of background light from all angles.

Use multiple (about 3 different) smaller stronger lamps opposed to a large lamp. A large lamp will generate soft shadow and large widely distributed highlights. Small lamps generate well defined falloffs and concentrated highlights.

Comment: Thanks for the tips regarding the background color and multiple smaller lamps. I think these helped but there's still this remaining flatness that I don't get with other textures. I'll keep playing with it.